# Prestashop 1.7 JS files not being added

Tags: themes, yaml, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

Working on Prestashop 1.7 and updated my theme.yml file to look like the below but it doesn't add in the file. The file is in that directory but it isn't being pulled in. Any suggestions to the code? I want to include the JS file but it isn't being pulled in.

```
assets:
  # If you're using this theme as child and you want to load
  # the parent theme assets, uncomment this line.
  # use_parent_assets: true

  # The following lines are showing how to load assets in your page
  # Uncomment and change value to start loading css or js files
 css:
   all:
     - id: theme-custom
       path: assets/css/custom.css
#    product:
#      - id: product-style
#        path: assets/css/product.css
#        media: all
#        priority: 200
 js:
   all:
      - id: slick
        path: assets/js/external-lib.js
        priority: 30
        position: bottom
   cart:
     - id: theme-custom
       path: assets/js/custom.js
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to mannually delete or rename the file

```
config/themes/{theme_name}/shop{shopid}.json
```

It has priority ove that one. It's already reported and solved for 1.7.1.
Then the code in your assets will be added to the cached one (to reduce the number of file loading).

Comment: Thank you, will I need to do that everytime I do a change in the theme.yml file?

Comment: It's reported to be fixed in 1.7.1. So until then, yes. I can confirm that with no cache activated, it will not recreate it, so there is no need to delete/change name.

Comment: Is this fixed to be automatic or not ? @sadlyblue

Comment: @kach I haven't tested it on later versions. But there was a mention in prestashop mentioning it was solved. Did you had this bug on later versions?

Comment: @sadlyblue no but I think that you can use the button "reset to defaults" in Backoffice in order to apply the modifications in theme.yml

Comment: Unfortunately this is not solved in 1.7.1, I am using Prestashop 1.7.6.1 and this problem is still present.