# confirmation message before deleting an item from cart

Tags: prestashop-1.7

Is there a way in prestashop to show a confirmation message before an item is removed from the cart in prestashop 1.7? I'd just like to be pointed to the file that contains this method so that I may be able to add a confirm dialog, since right now a user can just delete without confirmin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can show confirm dialog before deleting item from cart. By default `core.js` and `theme.js` file handles all events and update cart accordingly on `updateCart` event. ([Refer more on events here](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/themes/reference/javascript-events/))

To overcome default behaviour adding `js` prior to `theme.js` will help us to prevent default click event. Follow below mentioned step by step guide to load you own `js` and add confirmation dialog on item delete.

1) Register your `js` in `theme.yml` ([More details here](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/themes/getting-started/asset-management/#registering-in-themes)) by adding below code under `assets`

*themes/{your_theme}/config/theme.yml*

```
assets:
  js:
    cart:
      - id: cart-extra-lib
        path: assets/js/cart-lib.js
        priority: 30
```

2) Create file `cart-lib.js` under `themes/{your_theme}/assets/js` and add below code into it.

*themes/{your_theme}/assets/js/cart-lib.js*

```
function refreshDataLinkAction() {
    $('[data-link-action="delete-from-cart"]').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('data-link-action', 'confirm-remove-item');
    });
}

$(document).on('click', '[data-link-action="confirm-remove-item"]', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to remove product from cart?')) {
        $(this).attr('data-link-action', 'delete-from-cart');
        $(this).trigger('click');
    }
    return false;
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    refreshDataLinkAction();
    prestashop.on('updatedCart', function (event) {
        refreshDataLinkAction();
    });
});
```

3) Now, to load your js file you need to delete file `config/themes/{your_theme}/shop1.json` ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42141685/prestashop-1-7-js-files-not-being-added))

4) Add products to cart and check cart; delete items you will see confirmation message. Attaching image for reference.

[image]