# Delete confirmation dialog when decreasing quantity to 0 (Prestashop 1.7)

Tags: javascript, prestashop-1.7

I followed the answer posted here to add confirmation dialog when deleting a product from cart:
[confirmation message before deleting an item from cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52302175/confirmation-message-before-deleting-an-item-from-cart)

Now I'm trying to do a similar thing, showing the same confirmation message when decreasing prouct quantity on cart from 1 to 0 using touchspin, and if confirmed, the product should be removed from the cart.

The script used for delete link is this one:

```
function refreshDataLinkAction() {
    $('[data-link-action="delete-from-cart"]').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('data-link-action', 'confirm-remove-item');
    });
}

$(document).on('click', '[data-link-action="confirm-remove-item"]', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to remove product from cart?')) {
        $(this).attr('data-link-action', 'delete-from-cart');
        $(this).trigger('click');
    }
    return false;
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    refreshDataLinkAction();
    prestashop.on('updatedCart', function (event) {
        refreshDataLinkAction();
    });
});
```

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Can you explain better what are you expecting and what is not working, or what is the actual result?

Comment: The above script it's the one used to show the confirmation dialog when clicking on the product delete icon. I'm trying to modify this script to use it on quantity touchsping used to decrease product quantity into cart. To show the confirmation message when the user try to set product quantity to 0. The problem it's that I have no idea on how to do this.