# How to add custom fonts in prestashop?

Tags: css, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have a fonts goes by name FuturaPT ,  I would like to use this font to my shopping cart ,

Here is what I have added to my shopping-cart module css

```
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'FuturaPT-Book';
    src: url('../fonts/FuturaPT-Book.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/FuturaPT-Book.woff2') format('woff2'),
      url('../fonts/FuturaPT-Book.woff') format('woff'),
      url('../fonts/FuturaPT-Book.ttf') format('truetype'),
      url('../fonts/FuturaPT-Book.svg#FuturaPT-Book') format('svg'),
      url('../fonts/FuturaPT-Book.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
  }
```

css

```
h1{
font-size: 36px;
font-family: "FuturaPT-Book";
}
```

Checking the chrome dev network I can see the font is loaded but no changes in my h1 ,

is this the right way to add custom fonts in prestashop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add custom font in `Prestashop` you can register your `fonts.css` which loads your custom fonts and add your css in `custom.css` files.

Follow below mentioned steps;

1) Register your `css` in theme.yml ([More details here](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/themes/getting-started/asset-management/#registering-in-themes)) by adding below code under `assets`

*themes/{your_theme}/config/theme.yml*

```
assets:
  css:
    all:
      - id: fonts
        path: assets/css/fonts.css
        priority: 30
```

2) Create file `fonts.css` under `themes/{your_theme}/assets/css` and add below code into it.

*themes/{your_theme}/assets/css/fonts.css*

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FuturaPT-Book';
    src: url('../fonts/FuturaPT-Book.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/FuturaPT-Book.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('../fonts/FuturaPT-Book.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/FuturaPT-Book.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/FuturaPT-Book.svg#FuturaPT-Book') format('svg'),
        url('../fonts/FuturaPT-Book.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

3) Now, to load your `css` file you need to delete file `config/themes/{your_theme}/shop1.json` ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42141685/prestashop-1-7-js-files-not-being-added))

4) Create `fonts` folder under `themes/{your_theme}/assests` and add all files related to fonts in this folder.

5) Add your `css` to in `custom.css` file

*themes/{your_theme}/assets/css/custom.css*

```
h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
    font-family: "FuturaPT-Book";
}
```

If this not work give `important` as below;

```
h1 {
    font-size: 36px !important;
    font-family: "FuturaPT-Book" !important;
}
```

After making all these changes check your shop.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Best way is waiting :D

https://github.com/PrestaShop/fontmanager

This free module is in progress and will be available shortly. then you can active it from your modules list on BO and upload your custom font.